# How to upgrade to latest version of React Native?

Tags: macos, react-native

How do you upgrade to the latest version of react? I've tried all the following but I'm still stuck at v0.58.6.

```
react-native upgrade

npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade
react-native-git-upgrade

react-native upgrade 0.61.0-rc.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to 0.60 and above is quite painful. It can not work with some command lines. You could try below step

1. Follow this link to update your project manually https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.58.6&to=0.62.0-rc.0
2. Unlink all libs that linked before `react-native unlink <package-name>`
3. Upgrade all your libs in package.json
4. Build and fix errors if any :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the best option to create new project in react native then install all old library in new project and all your source code it is less time taking and I have tried it many time and it works without any problem.